How to apply symbolRenderingMode to a single toolbar button?
Consider the following code:
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack {
            Text("Text")
                .navigationTitle("Title")
                .toolbar {
                    Button("Button", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill", action: {})
                        .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
                        .foregroundStyle(.blue)
                }
        }
    }
}

I would expect the following:

But I get this instead:

If I modify the code by adding a second button,
.toolbar {
    HStack {
        Button("Button", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill", action: {})
            .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)

        Button("Button", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill", action: {})
            .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
    }
}

I get the expected:

However, this is of course far from ideal. I tried adding an "empty" Button("", action: {}) instead to the HStack and it works, but it's really just a hack.
Any ideas ?

Try using .tint instead of .foregroundStyle.

@BenzyNeez The issue is not the colour, it's the rendering mode.

When creating the button's image yourself, the color is respected:
.toolbar {
  Button(action: {}) {
    Image(systemName: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill")
      .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
      .foregroundStyle(.blue)
}

Looks like a bug in Button.

It works if you apply the .symbolRenderingMode using your own custom ButtonStyle:
struct ToolbarButton: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .symbolRenderingMode(.hierarchical)
            .foregroundStyle(.blue)
    }
}

.toolbar {
    Button("Button", systemImage: "line.3.horizontal.decrease.circle.fill", action: {})
        .buttonStyle(ToolbarButton())
}



This works great, thanks! I would add, in case someone needs this to work on a Menu, that it works only when adding the .menuStyle(.button) modifier to the menu.
